How to use -map to pick certain tracks based on english/5.1 etc
Good day all. Using ffmpeg I'm trying to auto select audio tracks based on language and type of stream but not sure on the syntax.
Below is an extract from my batch file, this relies on me feeding the right track number.
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 "%%~dpni.mp4"
I know I can select all english tracks using
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:m:language:eng "%%~dpni.mp4"
But how do I just select the 5.1 english track if there is one...ultimately auto converting dts if that is all available but lets not run before I can walk :D

Hello, ffmpeg is a CLI tool. So instead of typing out 5 paragraphs, prioritize providing a command that you're trying to work with. Else this is closeable.  This is not a free scripting service to write one for you.

No problem, you can edit the question then to ask for a specific problem you don't understandmwhile mentioning the documentation and examples  that didn't work for you.
